# why i cannot checkout another git branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-diff, git-checkout

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/lab_master
  remotes/origin/master

$ git checkout lab_master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkou                                                                                                                           t:
        **project.properties**
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

why i just failed to checkout lab_master branch?

another question: why i cannot compare current file with the file in another branch?

```
$ git diff project.properties -b lab_master
fatal: bad flag '-b' used after filename
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Git protects you from switching to another branch, because that would override some changes you applied to the file `project.properties`. You can either throw the changes away by using `git checkout -f lab_master` or stash them first via `git stash` (and `git stash pop` after you checked out the other branch.) If you are sure, you want to keep the changes, you can also simply commit them.

Comment: so does git stash can be used across branches?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either commit your changes or stash them, http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: the issue is that i want to commit the changes to lab_master branch, not the current master branch...

Answer (score 0):

git diff already uses the -b flag to ignore whitespace.
That conflicts with your desire to refer to another branch.
For that you need to use 'git diff master..anotherbranch'